# Dropbox permission is only set to view

Tags: dropbox

I am sharing a folder with with other people and something strange is happening.
Each one of us has his own domain as only one of us has a paid account.

The strange thing that is happening is this: I've added a new person to the share folder and this person only have "Can view" as permission. This means that I cannot change her permissions to "Can edit".

Any Ideas on how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest sending this question directly to [Dropbox support](https://www.dropbox.com/support). We monitor StackOverflow for questions about the API rather than the product.

Comment: I thought was a general issue. Thanks anyway.